# Help identifying book that started me reading Sci-Fi, but I never read - about aquatic Leviathan?

Tags: story-identification

When I was in grade school (maybe '69/'70) I overheard two classmates discussing a book about a scientist/family searching the ocean for a very large creature - the *Leviathan* I believe.  This lead me to the school library where I could supply neither title or author; however, she introduced me to the Sci-Fi section of the bookshelf. This was the event started me reading and over the years I've wondered about the identity of this book I never did find.

My primary recollection was that the *Leviathan* was considered more of a myth and they were attempting to prove it had once and maybe still existed.  I seem to recall a father that was a scientist.  I always thought it might have been a *Tom Swift* or *Johnny Quest* kind of story, but never encountered one with that kind of plot.

Comment: Can you recall anything else? I can think of a number of books about leviathans, including some where scientists are searching for them. As this is, it might be a bit too broad to identify the book.

Comment: This question will have two small issues: **1.** It is very vague and broad so it will be difficult to find an answer to **2.** How will *you* know which is the right/wrong answer?

Comment: Can you remember any more details you might have overheard? Are those classmates of yours contactable at all? Please also tell us what you've tried/ruled-out.

Comment: Agreed. I am voting to close as “Too Broad” due to the lack of detail, but there’s also the *significant* problem of the asker not being able to determine the correct answer.

Comment: @Adamant sorry I have no more to offer.  This is just a memory of a memory over 4 decades old.  The Zelazny lead may be promising.

Comment: Unless you're able to locate your former classmates, how are you going to know that any answer containing a leviathan will be the book you're after?

Comment: Was it a book from the school library? If so, where was this school located?

Comment: Secret Under the Sea is a 1960 young adult book by Gordon Dickson.  The protagonist lives in an undersea station with his scientist father and the plot revolves around a giant undersea monster.

Answer (score 6):

Could be "The Doors of His Face, The Lamps of His Mouth" by Roger Zelazny (1965), a short story found in  the collection of the same name(*). It involves the search for the *Ichthyform Leviosaurus Levianthus*.

(*) Yes, I know you said probably not a short story, but I'm throwing it out there anyway.

Comment: Reasonable cast.  Considering the age and the classmate I seem to recall it to be, a short story might be plausible.  Zelazny is one of my favorite authors, but I tend to avoid short stories, so I've never read this.  Worth a shot.  Thanks.

Comment: Finally found "The Doors of His Face, the Lamps of His Mouth" in Volume One of _The Collected Stories of Roger Zelazny_ - _Threshold_.  It's possible this was the story, but I'm going to keep looking.  My recollection was of a myth they were attempting to prove, not an actual creature they were attempting to capture.

Answer (score 5):

The timing is a bit off, but the description made me think of [The Illuminatus! Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Illuminatus!_Trilogy) by Robert Shea and Robert Anton Wilson. It was first published in 1975 as three separate books, *The Eye in the Pyramid*, *The Golden Apple*, and *Leviathan*. It was first collected in a single volume in 1984.

[image]

The main plot of the trilogy is not concerned with any leviathan, but (as the title may have given away) the third book *is*. The scientist or family searching for it would be Hagbard Celine and the other protagonists, on board of a golden submarine.

The trilogy famously introduced the word *fnord*.

Comment: have read this trilogy.  The publishing date of the third volume is not unreasonable for the timing. Unlikely this would have been in our grade school library; but not impossible.  Less likely the classmate I seem to recall talking about it would have been able to stick with this book at that age.

Comment: @ELKnoll As I'm not a native speaker, I needed to look it up to see that grade school is elementary school. Seems unlikely. This question is now closed, so I can't add it as an answer, but have you considered Wyndham's _The Kraken Wakes_?

Comment: I definitely don't recall the conversation including any discussion of aliens, so I'm going to say this was probably not it.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a reach here. Possibly Jack Vance's Blue World. People who are descendants of crashlanders on a planet entirely covered in water, who live atop town-sized lily pads. They constantly have to deal with a kraken that has through the generations grown larger and larger and eats more and more of their sacrifices- though a fish, it has become something of a religious icon, with a dedicated priesthood.

The book follows the adventures of a semaphorist (called a hoodwink) as he finds himself banished from his profession, and tries to see if he can drag his people back into something approaching the Iron Age.